# Excel: Create relationships between cells or lines

Tags: excel, filter, relationship

I've got a table of csv data. The lines may be related by order. I need to filter for both, regarding their relationship.

```
Example table:
   Type    Result    Test name
1: main    ok        something
2: main    ok        very important
3: sub     nok       unimportant
4: main    ok        unimportant
5: sub     not       unimportant
6: sub     ok        unimportant
```

I want to filter for line 2, because it is a important task which was tested 'ok' but it has a related sub-task which was 'nok'.
Line 3 is assigned to the last main task which is line 2. There is no relationship other than a sub task stands below a main task.

To summarize:
I want to filter for all sub-tasks which are 'nok' but only if they are assigned to a main-task which is 'very important'. Line 3 belongs to line 2 because it follows line 2.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is now the following:

There are two additional columns for processing "RelevantMain" and "PossibleRelevantSub" and on column for the result "RelevantSub". Each column is filled by one macro function.

```
Public Function getRelevantMain(typ As String, gt As String)
    matchesType = isEq(typ, "main")
    Dim conditionsGT As Variant
    conditions = Array("important values")
    matches = matchesList(gt, conditions)
    getRelevantMain = getRet(matchesType = True And matches = True)
End Function

Public Function getPossibleRelevantAdd(typ As String, prevRelMain As String, prevPossRelAdd As String)
    isAdd = isEq(typ, "add")
    prevWasRelMain = prevRelMain = "x"
    prevWasPossRelAdd = prevPossRelAdd = "x"
    prevWasRelevant = prevWasRelMain Or prevWasPossRelAdd
    getPossibleRelevantAdd = getRet(isAdd And prevWasRelevant)
End Function

Public Function getRelevantAdd(possRelAdd As String, rating As String)
    Dim conditionsRating As Variant
    conditionsRating = Array("nok types")
    matchesRating = matchesList(rating, conditionsRating)
    thisIsPossRelAdd = possRelAdd = "x"
    getRelevantAdd = getRet(thisIsPossRelAdd And matchesRating)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is how I would do this.  Add a formula to the 4th column (let's call it column D, not shown in your picture).  The formula in cell D2 would be:

```
==IF(A1="main", IF(C1="very important", IF(A2="sub",IF(B2="nok", TRUE,FALSE))))
```

This would create a TRUE statement for all tasks that are 'main' and 'very important' in the previous row, 'sub' and 'nok' in the current row.  See pic below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is also common in my case to have multiple sub-tasks. All 'nok' sub-tasks need to be filtered if the last main-task above it 'very important'. Do you think this is even possible without macro magic?

Comment: sure.  You can perhaps add a second filter (next column in E).  Formula in E2 would be:   =IF(A2="sub", IF(D1=TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)